# Qml Vertical Text Orientation

Tags: qt, qml

How can I display a text in QML with vertical orientation like below

```
Text {
    id: name13
    text: qsTr("KITCHEN")
}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but currently this can't be done directly through some setting of the Text element. You can use the column approach and create your own element or you can use the Wrapping feature to force it to wrap after every letter.

Answer (score 4):

Set `width` to 1, and `wrapMode` to `Text.WrapAnywhere`. This forces each letter to appear on its own line.

```
Text {
    text: "KITCHEN"
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    color: "white"
    width: 1
    wrapMode: Text.WrapAnywhere

    // -- additional parameters for prettiness --
    lineHeight: 0.9
    font.pixelSize: 50
    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
}
```

<sup>[QMLOnline KDE Demo](https://qmlonline.kde.org/?code=JYWwDg9gTgLgBARRggrsAxgazgJgHQDsAUKJLIsmlngMIQB2MUEANgM654DMRRASgFN0MAIb0A5iwFwA3kTgK46VtABccAEQAjFiKwb5isegAW0NngBmwFi3VgRUAY16K4AFQEAPeHLduYbxh1DQBpAEl3GgAJAFEAOQN-I3pTczx0Z0CocPp7RyzDZOUWNU0AdxNgQKTkuHLgABMYE3UARiL-cqgRMABZCEaBdU8fPAB1HrAAQXoAT0qBJ063FmB6AWiBYHETYLgABjwAThXFSwYYPDBgLwEWAGVgAC9huABWA7OFMygXy5ELGma3E9BAWRGQTwwJ29GiNCyS06AF8iKigA)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

In the following example, I use `Frame` to allow you to set the background to `grey`. I used `Column` with a `Repeater` and I break up the `"KITCHEN"` string with `split()` and render each character in its own `Text` component:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Frame {
    background: Rectangle { color: "grey" }
    Column {
        Repeater {
            model: "KITCHEN".split("")
            Text {
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                text: modelData
                font.pointSize: 24
                color: "white"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: kitchen-vertical-png]